# wrong value from inputText in datatable within accordionPanel

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

I have the following in my xhtml

```
              <p:accordionPanel id="existing-list" value="#{eventBean.registrations}" var="entry" >
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{eventBean.onRegistrationTabChange}" update="existing" />
              <p:tab title="#{entry.fullName}" >
              <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
              <h:panelGrid id="car" columns="1" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" styleClass="centre-content">
                <rich:dataTable value="#{entry.formFields}" var="field" id="table" columnClasses="field-label,field-value">
                  <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{field.fieldLabel}"/>
                  </rich:column>
                  <rich:column>
                    <h:inputText value="#{field.fieldValue}" size="#{field.length}"  rendered="#{field.fieldType == 'text'}">
                      <f:ajax/>
                    </h:inputText>
                  </rich:column>   
                </rich:dataTable>
                <h:commandButton action="#{formBean.refreshForm}" immediate="true" styleClass="refresh-button" 
                                 style="background-color: white; background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                                 background-image: url('images/refresh.gif');background-position: top;background-size: cover;"/>
              </h:panelGrid>
              <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                        <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{eventBean.savePreviousEntry}" styleClass="mailme-button"/>
                        <h:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{eventBean.cancelPreviousEntry}" immediate="true" 
                                         styleClass="mailme-button" render="panel-outer"/>
              </h:panelGrid>

              </h:panelGrid>
              </p:tab>
          </p:accordionPanel>
```

registrations is an ArrayList of EventRegistration objects, 
each EventRegistration contains an ArrayList of FormField objects, 
FormField contains attributes for fieldLabel and fieldValue

In my example I have 32 entries in registrations, in each registration, there are two FormFields in the ArrayList.

When the accordion panel displays, you can open each tab up in turn and the correct values for the fieldValue attributes is displayed, however when the Save button is pressed, the setFieldValue method of the first FormField object of the first registration gets called 32 timesset (once for each registration in the list) so that the  field value gets progressively replaced by the relevant fieldValue for each registration and ends up with the fieldValue of the last registration.

I added the f:ajax after the inputText to see what happened when the field was changed, this worked as expected when focus left the field.

What am I missing?

PF 5.3, faces 2.2.8-10, Java 7

Comment: Does it work with a plain `ui:repeat`?

Comment: I haven't tried that, I will give it a go - thanks

Comment: The ui:repeat works, thanks for the suggestion, it looks like the p:datatable has a problem when inside an accordian panel

Comment: Correct even in newer versions. Check the issuelist